# Is there any network connection observer available in .net?

Tags: .net, observers, internet-connection

Is there an observer available in .NET which notifies when the host's internet connection gets connected or disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

The `NetworkAvailabilityChanged` event of the [NetworkChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) class is probably the closest you get. Please refer to the following article for more information.

**Detect Internet Network Availability:** https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64975/Detect-Internet-Network-Availability